# Crystal report download fails in IE since exceeding 2083 characters

Tags: asp.net, .net, internet-explorer, crystal-reports, query-string

I am using Crystal Reports in my project to display and download reports. My project is basically developed in .Net. I get the user selection from my screen and pass the same to business objects server via query string. I face a problem here when the number of parameters is more. The query string length exceeds 2083 characters and hence the report download breaks in IE, whereas it works fine in any other browser. So please help me if there is any case this restriction of IE can be neglected.

If you want any more details let me know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As this [Microsoft Support page](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/208427) page suggests

> Microsoft Internet Explorer has a maximum uniform resource locator (URL) length of 2,083 characters. Internet Explorer also has a maximum path length of 2,048 characters. **This limit applies to both POST request and GET request URLs**.

Along with that it also suggests a workaround:

> the POST method is not limited by the size of the URL for submitting **name/value pairs**. These pairs are transferred in the header and not in the URL.

So the workaround is that, on the page from where you call the report/build url parameter you use **hidden field(s)** on that page, then assign required url parameter value(s) to the hidden field(s) and use post method to submit them to the report viewer page where you can access them via `request` object.